# How to open file picker in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Please suggest a **file picker for both platforms support** ios and android.

https://pub.dev/documentation/file_picker/latest/

above URL plugin I am using but not working in the ios app please suggest any new plugin.

```
 FilePickerResult result = await FilePicker.platform.pickFiles(
                        type: FileType.custom,
                        allowedExtensions: ['png', 'cdr', 'psd'],
                      );

                      if(result != null) {
                        files = File(result.files.single.path);

                        setState(() {
                          filePath = files.path;
                          fileName = (filePath.split('/').last);
                          print("File Path Select---" + files.path.toString());
                        });
                      } else {
                        // User canceled the picker
                      }
```

Thank you

Comment: What's not working? Did you read the implementation for iOS ? You need to setup a few things before it can work.

Comment: yes I read and follow but images are not showing in the file picker.

Comment: if you want to pick only images then you can use image_picker

Comment: Add some code that you have tried so far.

Comment: I added code...

Answer (score 3):

I use file_picker: ^1.13.3

The next code works fine for me

```
File file = await FilePicker.getFile(type: FileType.custom, allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png']);
```